# How to read a pdf response from Rails app and save to file with parallel tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest

Ok - I have the following in my `test/test_helper.rb`:

```
def read_pdf_from_response(response)
  file = Tempfile.new
  file.write response.body.force_encoding('UTF-8')
  begin
    reader = PDF::Reader.new(file)
    reader.pages.map(&:text).join.squeeze("\n")
  ensure
    file.close
    file.unlink
  end
end
```

I use it like this in an integration test:

```
get project_path(project, format: 'pdf')
read_response_from_pdf(@response).tap do |pdf|
  assert_match(/whatever/, pdf)
end
```

This works fine as long as I run a test singly or when running all tests with only one worker, e.g. `PARALLEL_WORKERS=1`. But tests that use this method will fail intermittently when I run my suite with more than 1 parallel worker. My laptop has 8 cores, so that's normally what it's running with.

Here's the error:
`PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError: PDF malformed, expected 5 but found 96 instead`

or sometimes: `PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError: PDF file is empty`

The PDF reader is https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader which hasn't given any problems.

The controller that sends the PDF returns like so:

```
send_file out_file,
          filename: "#{@project.name}.pdf",
          type: 'application/pdf',
          disposition: (params[:download] ? 'attachment' : 'inline')
```

I can't see why this isn't working. No files should ever have the same name at the same time, since I'm using Tempfile, right? How can I make all this run with parallel tests?

Answer (score 1):

While I cannot confirm why this is happening the issue may be that:

1. You are forcing the encoding to "UTF-8" but PDF documents are binary files so this conversion could be damaging the PDF.
2. Some of the responses you are receiving are truly empty or malformed.

Maybe try this instead:

```
def read_pdf_from_response(response)
  doc = StringIO.new(response.body.to_s)
  begin
    PDF::Reader.new(doc)
      .pages
      .map(&:text)
      .join
      .squeeze("\n")
  rescue PDF::Reader::MalformedPDFError => e
    # handle issues with the pdf itself
  end 
end
```

This will avoid the file system altogether while still using a compatible `IO` object and will make sure that the response is read as binary to avoid any conversion conflicts.

Comment: This solution works about like the one in the answer does - it works fine with only 1 worker, but intermittently fails with parallel testing.

Comment: I did have to take out the `File.binread` part. Using it lead to frequent `ArgumentError: path name contains null byte` results.

Comment: @croceldon can you confirm that the same files that error with multiple workers work otherwise? `binread` was my fault (I was considering using your `Tempfile` and then didn't and I missed removing it.)

Comment: Yes - they all work fine if run without parallel tests, or if run just one at a time.

Comment: Then it sounds like the issue is that the request => response is the issue either it is timing out and coming back empty/malformed or there is throttling or something to that effect. I would still recommend avoiding the creation of a `Tempfile` but can you explain/post more about the pdf response process?

Comment: I've added more detail on how the PDF is sent. It's created by the prawn library, then sent using the `send_file` method, as shown in the edited question.

Comment: @croceldon is `out_file` also a `Tempfile`? Can you post a bit more of the code? Generally for prawn generated pdf documents we use `send_data` and `pdf.render` to avoid the creation of an actual file but i am not sure if this helps/hurts in your case.

Comment: It's not a `Tempfile`, it's a file location on disk of the generated PDF. Will have to see if `send_data` makes a difference.